# Chart.js line 2686 Error

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, sinatra, erb

I want lineChart of Chart.js in my sinatra application. But firefox console says

```
`TypeError:this.scale is undefined(Chart.js:2686)`
```

and, lineChart is not displayed.I wrote following code.

@hello.erb

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Chartjs/Chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="line" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

@script.js

```
$(function(){
    var lineChartData = {
    labels : ["hoge","fuga"],
    datasets : [
    {
        fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        data : [60,70]
    } ]
}

var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("line").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData);
});
```

When I write this code in NOT sinatra(erb), it works correctly.  What should I do modify?

Answer (score 0):

Check the developer tools of your browser (often, press F12) and see in the Network tab if the files are loaded correctly - press F5 to reload the page. It might be that your script files are not loaded, in that case prepend a slash (`<script src='/script.js' ...>`) . Are the javascript files located in your `public` directory?

Comment: Thank you for your answering.But I add "alert("hoge")" to script.js and reload mypage, alert displayed.So I think script.js is loaded...

Comment: Try again pressing F12 or opening developer tools. More informative than your alert. One of the other scripts might not load. Knowing what the browser sees is better than thinking to know what the browser sees.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem looks like a timing problem. Since your canvas element is not present when your script runs.

With Jquery you can just wrap your chart statement in a document.ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("line").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData);
}
```

For a non Jquery solution I recommend https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899701/1279355